# Hows does XJC order elements

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

I am having some troubles with my JAVA classes generated from a schema and had a question,

How does the XJC decided the order that the elements are written to when marshaling the JAVA objects to XML?

In the generated classes it creates the annotation `@XmlType` with the order but this is different to the order that they appear in the schema.

Can anyone help with how the ordering of the annotation takes place during compilation or any links on documentation that could help?

Answer (score 1):

JAXB will use the `propOrder` property on the `@XmlType` annotation to match the order XML elements will occur based on the rules defined in the XML Schema.  In the case of type inheritance the elements defined on the super class will appear before the elements defined on the subclass.  This matches XML Schema rules.

If you are seeing different behaviour can you update your question with an example.